# Typing colon character in Insert mode undoing changes?

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings, insert-mode

I am really curious as to why this is happening. I have this line in my .vimrc file (I am using WSL2 on windows and this line helps support copying from vim to the system clipboard):

```
set clipboard=unnamedplus " system copy-paste support 1. get vim-gtk 2. set this 3. for WSL, vcxsrv and set option in .bashrc
```

Disregarding the bad practice of making such a long line, I noticed something curious. When I enter insert mode my cursor is just at the space after the word "support". I backspace to delete "support". I type in "also:", and the moment I insert the colon character, the change is undone, and I am moved to normal mode. The line goes back to the state I was, as if I had never changed it.

What on earth could be causing this?

The full `.vimrc` is probably too big to fit on this question. I know that external sites like pastebin are not recommended, however I do not know where else to put it, so, this is my entire `.vimrc`: https://pastebin.com/gD45NYEX (let me know if there is a better place to put it). Thank you for all the help.

Again, here is the [link to my full .vimrc](https://pastebin.com/gD45NYEX)

Comment: "Part of my `.vimrc`"---that's probably not enough to identify the root cause. See [How to debug my vimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/10604)

Comment: `:verbose imap :` might be insightful.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I posted my entire vimrc as a pastebin link, as it would be too much to fit into one question, as per etiquette on stack exchange communities, I believe. Please let me know what other changes I should make to make sure that everyone can access my `.vimrc`

Comment: @JakeGrossman `verbose imap :` says "No mapping found" unfortunately.

Comment: @herophant the idea is we dont need the whole vimrc—follow the link I gave you